# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'legume'}'

Tags: python, django, web

Everytime I run my django project, I get this error `NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'legume'}'`. I want to list my products and to be honest, I don't even know what the problem is.

Full trace: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'product_list_by_category' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'legume'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P\w+)/$']
[29/Nov/2017 22:18:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 180670

My main **URLS**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from  django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('shop.urls', namespace = 'shop'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My **Models.py** page

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120 , db_index = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200 , db_index = True , unique= True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return  reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id','slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

My app **URLS**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>\w+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

Here is my **Base.HTML**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}AgroShop{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel = stylesheet href = '{% static "css/base.css" %}'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href="/" class = "logo">AgroShop</a>
    </div>

    <div class="subheader">
        <div class="cart">
            {% with total_items=cart|length %}
                {% if cart|length > 0 %}
                    Your cart :
                    <a href="{% url "cart:cart_detail" %}">
                        {{ total_items }} item{{ total_items|pluralize }}
                    </a>
                {% else %}
                    Your cart is empty.
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**List.HTML**

```
{% extends 'shop/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    {% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}{{ Products }}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="sidebar">
        <h3>Categories:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li {% if not category %} class="selected">{% endif %}>
                <a href="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}">All</a>
            </li>
        {% for c in categories %}
            <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %} class = 'selected{% endif %}'>
                <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="main" class="product-list">
        <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}</h1>
        {% for product in products %}
            <div class="item">
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/dirig.jpg' %}{% endif %}" alt="">
                </a>
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a><br>
                {{ product.price }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `category_slug` in the URL pattern, but have `slug` when you call reverse. Make sure that the URL pattern, `get_absolute_url` method and view all match.

Answer (score 0):

[You can use either:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

`reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', kwargs={"category_slug": "myslug"})`

Or:

`reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', args=["myslug"])`

But `reverse('shop:product_list_by_category', kwargs={'slug': "myslug"})`
does not work since the key `slug` in your kwarg does not match the argument in your url which is `category_slug`